# Facebook Long Token: you must provide or set a default application secret

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

Im using Facebook PHP SDK to exchange a short lived token for a new long lived token.
As it says [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending), you should just call a URL with these parameters:

```
GET /oauth/access_token?
 client_id={app-id}
&client_secret={app-secret}
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

If I call this directly in browser, it works ok. I could just do a curl call and that would be ok. But I want stay close the oficial FacebookSDK, so in my Class I did this method:

```
public function renewToken($userShortToken, $redirectURI = FALSE) {

    if ($redirectURI !== FALSE)
        $this->redirectURI = $redirectURI;

    $this->fbSession = new FacebookSession($userShortToken);
    $params = '/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token' .
                '&client_id=' . $this->appId .
                '&client_secret=' . $this->appSecret . 
                '&fb_exchange_token=' . $userShortToken .
                '&appsecret_proof=' . hash_hmac('sha256', $userShortToken, $this->appSecret);
    # About appsecret_proof: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests
    $this->debug->log('params', $params);
    
    try {
        $request = new FacebookRequest($this->fbSession, 'GET', $params);
        $this->debug->log('request', $params);
        $response = $request->execute();
        $this->debug->log('response', $response);
        $object = $response->getGraphObject();
        return $object;
        
    } catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
        $this->debug->log('FacebookRequestException', $ex);
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        $this->debug->log('FacebookRequestException', $ex->getMessage());
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

PS: the "$userShortToken" is sent via Ajax to the server, after the user has logged in my website through Facebook Javascritp SDK.

So I see in my console these errors (im using FirePHP to output messages to console):

> /oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=305...57&client_secret=759...6c4&fb_exchange_token=CAAEV...lR&appsecret_proof=2e...76
>
> You must provide or set a default application secret. FacebookRequestException /myserver/.../socialshare/MyClass.php:96

I cant understanding this message. I setted the app secret, the short token, all the necessary parameters in the URL. Even the "appsecret_proof" hash. It is all correct. If I copy the url and call the graph, it works and give me back the long Token.

Does someone have an idea how to stick with FacebookSDK or I should just drop that for this task? I just want to do this in the most correct possible way.

Thank you.

Comment: _“But I want stay close [to] the oficial FacebookSDK”_ – well then why don’t you actually _do_ that? `FacebookSession->getLongLivedSession` exists.

Answer (score 0):

When I get this error it helped me to call

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($fbAppId, $fbAppSecret);
```

before creating a `FacebookSession`